# HTML output into text

Tags: javascript

I am using a WYSIWYG for text formatting. AT some point I need to grab that text and email it in a text format. So I'm trying to strip all HTML tags while preserving line breaks and paragraphs.

Also I decided to preserve bullet list and replace the bullets with "-".

```
var txt = $('#myEditor').summernote('code')
          .replace(/<\/p>/gi, "\n")
          .replace(/<br\/?>/gi, "\n")
          .replace(/<li\/?>/gi, " \n- ")
          .replace(/<ol\/?>/gi, " \n- ")
          .replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");
```

It seems to be working ALMOST OK with one exception. The following HTML code:

lumps a paragraph line with the last list item:

> Some demo sentence here.

- Unordered list item 1
- Unordered list item 2
  One more sentence here.
- Ordered list item
- Ordered list item two

$('#myEditor').summernote('code') returns:

```
<p>Some demo sentence here.</p><ul><li>Unordered list item 1</li><li>Unordered list item 2<br></li></ul><p>One more sentence here.<br></p><ol><li>Ordered list item</li><li>Ordered list item two<br></li></ol>
```

Comment: What does `$('#myEditor').summernote('code')` return?

Comment: @guest271314 I've updated my post.

Comment: Is expected result for text within each element be placed on a separate line?

Comment: @santa Please post the failure code and the expected output

Answer (score 0):

If expected result is for the text content of each element returned by `$("#myEditor").summernote("code")` to be placed on a separate line, you can use `.contents()`, `.map()`, `.trim()` to concatenate `"\n"` following value of each elements `.nodeValue` or `.textContent`

```js
var htmlStr = "<p>Some demo sentence here.</p><ul><li>Unordered list item 1</li><li>Unordered list item 2<br></li></ul><p>One more sentence here.<br></p><ol><li>Ordered list item</li><li>Ordered list item two<br></li></ol>";

var res = "";

$(htmlStr).contents().map(function(i, el) {
  var curr = (el.nodeValue || el.textContent).trim();
  if (curr.length) res += curr + "\n"
});

console.log(res);

$("pre").text(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using [lynx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lynx_%28web_browser%29), a text-based web browser, which does essentially what you're trying to do: display a web page as text.

Within Lynx, you can press `p` to "print" the page to a text file.

Comment: I need both outputs. One is used for HTML email and the plain-text version for text messages as an alternative.